# mysql sum query with exceptions

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, having

I have the following MySQL query which works very well for me:

```
SELECT *, SUM(col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5) AS sumtotal FROM table GROUP BY number HAVING sumtotal > 50;
```

However, now I need to make this query a bit more complicated by adding certain exceptions. Basically I need to exclude rows where col1 + col2 is greater than fifty or where col4 + col5 is greater than fifty. The idea is to find all the rows where this sum is somewhat "balanced" across all of the columns instead of being "tilted" to the left or right. Something like this:

```
SELECT *, SUM(col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5) AS sumtotal FROM table GROUP BY number HAVING sumtotal > 50 UNLESS SUM(col1 + col2) > 50 OR SUM(col4 + col5) > 50;
```

I can easily achieve my end result by doing some additional PHP math karate, but this is very messy and seems like extra work - so I would like to try to write better queries with MySQL instead.

Comment: Line breaks are allowed in queries. They would make the query much easier to read both for you and for us.

Comment: you're so nearly there, it seems implausible that you cannot figure this out for yourself- although strictly speaking a normalised schema would probably work better

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. `UNLESS condition` can be written as `AND NOT condition`, or just `AND` and reversing the comparison operator:

```
SELECT 
  number,  -- * ? 
  SUM(col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5) AS sumtotal 
FROM 
  table 
GROUP BY number 
HAVING 
  sumtotal > 50 
  AND SUM(col1 + col2) <= 50 
  AND SUM(col4 + col5) <= 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it to `Where` clause

```
select sum (col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5 ) ab 
    from tab1 
    where col1 + col2 <50 and col4 + col5 < 50
    group by number 
    having sum (col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5 ) > 50
```